# Run Python script that affect parent shell (changes environment variables, runs other scripts, etc.)

Tags: python, bash, process, environment-variables, virtualenv

Recently I need to affect bash shell that runs python script from python script itseft. I develop a [Python utility package](https://pypi.org/project/to-requirements.txt/) that add some additional functionallity to `pip`. One of the workflows in this package needs to active Virtualenv to work as planned. Here is the problem.

When you run something like:

```py
os.system('/bin/bash ./venv/bin/activate')
```

Or:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', './venv/bin/activate')
```

It doesn't do anything to the shell when the script is executed. Basically because these commands are executed in isolated processes (I guess) and therefore does not affect bash process itself.

**Question:** how can you affect parent shell that execute python script from inside the script (add some environments, run other script, etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the whole point of a subprocess is that it *doesnt* do that. Once the Python process executes, the bash process that launched it might not even exist. So while there might be some hack available, maybe it would be better to rethink how this is all supposed to work to begin with. So, the bash shell should source the environment *and then* run Python, once you run Python, it's *already too late*

Comment: It's not possible to change environment variables in a parent process, not in any language. When this is needed, the solution is for the program to output the variable assignment statements, then the parent script uses `eval` to execute the output. For examples, see `tset` and `ssh-agent`.

Comment: One possible solution is to wrap your Python script in a shell script that does something like `./venv/bin/activate; exec python myscript.py`, but note, this won't affect the parent shell that ran that if it is run as a script, unless you use `source mywrapper` (which will work in the current shell). But you should probably explain *why* you need to source the environment. Generally, that shouldn't be the programs responsibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can you affect parent shell that execute python script from inside the script (add some environments, run other script, etc.)?

It is not possible to do that, unless your operating system is broken. Process isolation is one of the very basic concepts of an operating system.

Instead, resaerch what `venv` does and how it works and what `activate` script does and just add the proper directory to python module search path.